# How to center a typewriter (ttfamily) '+'

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes, typewriter

I would like to draw a circular TikZ node with `+` in its center, but `font=\ttfamily` moves it up. Why? How to solve it?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    or/.style = {circle,    
        minimum size=4mm,  
        very thick,  
        draw,  
        font=\ttfamily, 
    },
]
\node[or,font=\normalfont] (a) {+};
\draw[very thin,red] (a.west)--(a.east);

\node[or] (b) at (1,0) {+};
\draw[very thin,red] (b.west)--(b.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The official center and the optical center do not need to lie at the same position. Every character has an official bounding box which is used by (La)TeX including packages like TikZ. This bounding box can be larger or smaller then the lines of the character. How the character is actually drawn is part of the fonts which is ignored by (La)TeX, AFAIK. So there is no automatic way to center the `+` because TeX doesn't know about this two lines which make up the plus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By design, the `+` in Computer Modern has its horizontal bar slightly above what we would consider the visual center; this "fools" TiKZ's algorithm for centering an object on the node coordinates.

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}

\newcommand{\ttplus}{%
  \raisebox{-.15ex}[\dimexpr\height-.15ex\relax][0pt]{\ttfamily+}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\hbox{\fboxsep=0pt \fboxrule=.2pt % just to have no sep and lighter rules
\fbox{+}\,a\,\fbox{\ttfamily+}\,\fbox{\ttplus}}
\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[
    or/.style = {circle,
        minimum size=4mm,
        very thick,
        draw,
    },
]
\node[or,font=\normalfont] (a) {+};
\draw[very thin,red] (a.west)--(a.east);

\node[or] (b) at (1,0) {\ttplus};
\draw[very thin,red] (b.west)--(b.east);

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just to add to egreg's fine answer. Why it moves up? TikZ will center the enclosing box, as is obvious from the image below:

[image]

TeX aligns the letters symbols at their baseline in text mode and at a centerline, if they are in maths mode. Kerning is a partial solution as egreg, showed. Having the `+` in math is a better solution. It is not just a font issue, but also the way TikZ aligns which is closer to mathmode. Better even design a small cross using TikZ and have it placed at the *exact*  center.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\boxes{\fbox{\fbox{y}\fbox{x}\fbox{+}\fbox{f}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    or/.style = {circle,    
        minimum size=6mm,  
        very thick,  
        draw,  
        font=\ttfamily, 
    },
]
\node[or,font=\normalfont] (a) {yx\textsuperscript{2}+};
\draw[very thin,red] (a.west)--(a.east);

\node[or] (b) at (1.3,0) {$x^2_3+$};
\draw[very thin,red] (b.west)--(b.east);
\fboxsep0pt\fboxrule0.1pt
\node[or] (c) at (2.5,0) {\fbox{\fbox{y}\fbox{x}\fbox{+}}};
\draw[very thin,red] (c.west)--(c.east);

\end{tikzpicture}

\texttt{\boxes} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you also for answering 'why?'. Your proposal of drawing a small cross is nice, I've already used it sometimes but I wanted to know if it was possible to avoid it.