# Creating a seamless XOR symbol as node

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I want to have a XOR node in my TikZ diagram, but couldn't find any available symbol, therefore made one myself, but I am not very happy with it.
I used the example from [how to draw XOR gate symbol as a node in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74958/how-to-draw-xor-gate-symbol-as-a-node-in-tikz) as basis.

```
\tikzstyle{XOR} = [draw,circle]
```

And use it as follows:

```
 \node [XOR] {\large +};
```

However, there is always a padding around the `+`. I want the `+` to 'connect' with the circle.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{XOR} = [draw,circle]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', scale = 1, transform shape]
    \tikzstyle{line}=[draw, -latex']

    \node (XOR-aa)[XOR] {\large +};


    \node [above of=XOR-aa,node distance=1.5cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=south,align=center] (bla) {Bla};

    \node [right of=XOR-aa,node distance=3cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=east,align=center] (Blob) {Blob};

    \node [left of=XOR-aa,node distance=3cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=west,align=center] (blubb) {Blubb};

    \path[line] (XOR-aa) edge (Blob)
                (bla) edge (XOR-aa)
                (blubb) edge (XOR-aa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\node (XOR-aa) {$\displaystyle\oplus$};` be what you need?

Comment: I think your question is similar to [how to draw XOR gate symbol as a node in tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74958/1952), although Claudio's answer is not there.

Comment: Well, I don't know if anyone who voted to close my answer, actually read my question? I even pointed to the other thread, but in my case the XOR-gate is connected to the circle. Oh well. Claudio answered it nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg Wow. I was actually looking for that symbol and couldn't find it.

Comment: @cherrung I've voted for reopening. At the least you should try and edit the title so that it's clear that you want a different thing than what's in the other question.

Comment: I voted to reopen too. Notice indeed that in the previous question [how to draw XOR gate symbol as a node in tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74958/how-to-draw-xor-gate-symbol-as-a-node-in-tikz) there's no mention about _how_ to draw the `XOR` symbol. Here, instead, the question is clearly: _how to draw an `XOR` symbol such that the `+` sign is connected to the external circle?_

Comment: I hope seamless describes it best. @egreg I think using `\oplus` is actually the most easy way, however, there is a padding between the arrows and the `\oplus`, which doesn't happen with the created `tikzset`.

Comment: Try with `\node[outer sep=0pt] (XOR-aa){$\displaystyle\oplus$};`. From manual: *This option adds an additional (invisible) separation space of hdimensioni outside the background path.
The main effect of this option is that all anchors will move a little “to the outside.”*

Comment: I was who first vote to close it, but now I also voted to reopen it. But, please, as egreg suggested, change the title. A second trick, when linking to another question just include the complete url, this site will replace it with its title which is more informative than just `here`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best idea I think is to define the `XOR` in such a way that automatically the `+` sign is inside the circle. One possibility is:

```
\tikzset{XOR/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
        [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
        (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
        (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
        }
    }
}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning,automata}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{XOR/.style={draw,circle,append after command={
        [shorten >=\pgflinewidth, shorten <=\pgflinewidth,]
        (\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)
        (\tikzlastnode.east) edge (\tikzlastnode.west)
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex',shorten <=1bp,shorten >=1bp}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    \node (XOR-aa)[XOR,scale=1.2] {};


    \node [above of=XOR-aa,node distance=1.5cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=south,align=center] (bla) {Bla};

    \node [right of=XOR-aa,node distance=3cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=east,align=center] (Blob) {Blob};

    \node [left of=XOR-aa,node distance=3cm,text width=1.5cm,anchor=west,align=center] (blubb) {Blubb};

    \path[line] (XOR-aa) edge (Blob)
                (bla) edge (XOR-aa)
                (blubb) edge (XOR-aa);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice in particular how the `line` is defined:

```
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex',shorten <=1bp,shorten >=1bp}}
```

The `shorten` allows that the arrows does not touch the `XOR`: without this, a departing arrow could be confused with the the `+`.

The result is:

[image]

The approach allows to scale the `XOR` symbol very easily without problems; for example using:

```
\node (XOR-aa)[XOR,scale=2.5] {};
```

in the previous MWE leads to:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Claudio's `XOR style`, following code provides a `xor shape` based in `forbidden sign` shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{xor}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \foregroundpath{
    \centerpoint%
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%  
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@yb%
    \else%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb%
    \fi%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[xor, draw=red, fill=red!30] (A) {};
\node[xor, draw, fill=green!30, right=1cm of A, minimum size=5mm, line width=.5mm] (B) {};
\draw (A)--(B);
\draw[<-] (A)--++(90:1cm) node[above](bla) {Bla};
\draw[->] (bla)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]