# Tikz, how to a simple new shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

I want to make a new shape for `switch` in my network diagram. 
It's really simple based on circle.

[image]

I got this manually by

```
\def \drawswitch {
  \node[circle,draw] (circle){};
  \draw (circle.south west) -- (circle.north east);
  \draw (circle.north west) -- (circle.south east);
}
```

but I still want to make it perfect by defining a new shape using `\pgfdeclareshape`, however I've no idea how to overwrite the `\backgroundpath`. I don't know how to find `saved anchor` a circle have and annotations like `\pgf@xb` confused me a lot .

Comment: If you are not writing anything inside this shape, then use `path picture`. The manual is pretty instructive on that.

Comment: You not necessarily need to work at PGF level; you might start from [Creating a seamless XOR symbol as node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75836/13304) (from that, few modifications are required to get a `switch`).

Comment: Since the shape does not have to expand to fit text inside, doing the anchors is easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next is the code for a `switch` shape. I've taken the code from the `forbidden sign` (`pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex`) and added the missing line.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{switch}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] % this is nearly a circle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \foregroundpath{
    \centerpoint%
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%  
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@yb%
    \else%
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb%
    \fi%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.707107\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[switch,draw,fill=red!30] (A) {Switch A};
\node[switch,draw,fill=red!30, right=1cm of A] (B) {Switch B};
\draw (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]