# How to decorate a node with additional paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to add styles to my nodes that draw additional paths inside of the node.

For example (without proper placement of nodes)

```
\node[draw,circle,lVert] {};
\node[draw,circle,lHor]  {};
\node[draw,circle,lVert,lHor] {};
```

shall result in these nodes:

[image]

### Keywords

strike through node, line in node, strike through style, cross, path as style

Comment: Seems similar to [Creating a seamless XOR symbol as node](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75836/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino There is a solution to my problem slumbering in the accepted answer to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapting the solution of the following question (thanks to Claudio's comment): [Creating a seamless XOR symbol as node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75836/creating-a-seamless-xor-symbol-as-node)

I ended up with this working and extremely simple code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw,circle},
    hVert/.style={append after command={(\tikzlastnode.north) edge (\tikzlastnode.south)}},
    hHorz/.style={append after command={(\tikzlastnode.west) edge (\tikzlastnode.east)}}
  ]
  \node[hVert] (a) {};
  \node[right=of a,hVert,hHorz] (f) {};
  \node[right=of f,hHorz] (b) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option: declare three new shapes.

It would be better to declare only one new shape with some parameter to draw horizontal, vertical or both lines, but I don't know how to do it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{hVert}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] % this is nearly a circle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \foregroundpath{
    \centerpoint% 
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x% 
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
  }
}
\pgfdeclareshape{hHorz}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] % this is nearly a circle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \foregroundpath{
    \centerpoint% 
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x% 
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
  }
}
\pgfdeclareshape{hVertHorz}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] % this is nearly a circle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \foregroundpath{
    \centerpoint% 
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x% 
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by -.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[hHorz,draw, thick, blue, fill=red!30] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[hVert,draw, red, fill=blue!30, minimum size=.75cm] (B) at (1,1) {};
\node[hVertHorz,draw, thick,fill=red!30!blue] (C) at (2,0) {};
\draw (A)--(B)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about this. But I'm going to require even more decorations and the number of shapes would grow exponentially. Also I need to decorate both circles and squares. But maybe this solution serves someone else.