# Decorate node with rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to distinguish vertices in a network by decorating them with additional paths. The solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160268/how-to-decorate-a-node-with-additional-paths) works perfectly for single lines, but I need more shapes so I also want to draw a small rectangle inside the node in the same manner. An attempt which in my eyes should work is shown below in `pat2` (`pat1` is just for comparison). The problem is that it doesn't, and I don't see why.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{cvertex}=[solid, circle,draw=black,line width=1 pt, inner sep=2pt]
\tikzset{
    local edge style/.style = {line width=1pt, line cap=round, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt},
    pat1/.style = {append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.west) 
        edge[local edge style] 
        (\tikzlastnode.east)
    }},
    pat2/.style = {append after command={
        [draw, line width=1pt]
        ($(\tikzlastnode.south west) + (1.4pt,1.4pt)$)
        rectangle
        ($(\tikzlastnode.north east) - (1.4pt,1.4pt)$)
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cvertex, pat1] at (0,0) {};
    \node [cvertex, pat2] at (0.3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still don't understand how it works, using `\pgfextra`+`\endpgfextra` commands surrounding `append after command` paths helps.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    cvertex/.style={solid, circle, draw=black,line width=1 pt, inner sep=2pt},
    local edge style/.style = {line width=1pt, line cap=round, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt},
    pat1/.style = {append after command={
           \pgfextra
        \draw (\tikzlastnode.west) 
        edge[local edge style] 
        (\tikzlastnode.east);
        \endpgfextra
    }},
    pat2/.style = {append after command={\pgfextra \draw[line width=1pt]
        ($(\tikzlastnode.south west) + (1.4pt,1.4pt)$)
        rectangle
        ($(\tikzlastnode.north east) + (-1.4pt,-1.4pt)$);
        \endpgfextra
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cvertex, pat1] at (0,0) {};
    \node [cvertex, pat2] at (0.5,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

With previous solution those `inside node decorations` won't survive to a [`fill` option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/why-fill-covers-append-after-command-elements), so I provide a better one based in `path picture`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    cvertex/.style={solid, circle, draw=black,line width=1 pt, inner sep=2pt},
    local edge style/.style = {line width=1pt, line cap=round, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, blue},
    pat1/.style = {path picture={
        \draw (path picture bounding box.west) 
        edge[local edge style] 
        (path picture bounding box.east);
    }},
    pat2/.style = {path picture={\draw[line width=1pt,local edge style]
        ($(path picture bounding box.south west) + (1.8pt,1.8pt)$)
        rectangle
        ($(path picture bounding box.north east) + (-1.8pt,-1.8pt)$);
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [cvertex, pat1, draw=red, fill=green] at (0,0) {};
    \node [cvertex, pat2, fill=red] at (0.5,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]