# Defining a tikz-shape for block mode diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape, pgffor

**What I want to do**

I want to draw diagrams of operation modes of block ciphers like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#/media/File:ECB_encryption.svg) of the ECB mode. I did this before without defining shapes for particular parts
of the diagram. However, this time I wanted to do it properly and define shapes for the XOR operation and the blocks of plaintext, ciphertext and IV.

For the XOR operation the [question has been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407126/23775). However, I need to define a new shape the blocks of plaintext, ciphertext and IV.

**My approach**

My approach now is to define a new shape based on the rectangle shape and draw 9 evenly distributed vertical lines inside the rectangle using a for loop. This then yields 10 compartments of the same size inside the rectangle. To do so I calculate the distance between two vertical lines. I then start from the saved anchor `north.east` and draw 9 vertical lines in the calculated distance. I did this in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{block}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is a rectanble
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]

  \foregroundpath{
    \setlength{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \setlength{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgf@xa / 10}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\northeast}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
    {%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}{\pgfpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-2\pgf@ya}}}
    }
  }
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tikzset{blockstyle/.style={draw, minimum width = 4cm, minimum height = 0.4cm, shape=block}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blockstyle] (p1) at (0.1cm,0.1cm)  {};
\node[above] at (p1.north) {Plaintext 1};x
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**The problem**

Drawing a block at `(0,0)` works fine, but as soon as a block is drawn at another position the drawing of the vertical lines is messed up with the lines drawn out of the rectangle as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Hence my question: *What is wrong with the calculation of the drawing of the lines?*

**EDIT** It seems the problems occurs when the node is not placed at `(0,0)`. This might be a hint towards the source of the problem. I adopted the MWE and the text accordingly.

Comment: @marmot I did just now but it did not change the result. I will edit the MWE accordingly.

Comment: The `\pgfpathmoveto` moves the current point to a new position. In this case the old position plus `\pgfpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}`. This (should) move the current position `\pgfutil@tempdima` to the left. `\pgfpathlineto` then only draws the line without changing the current position if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Yes `\pgfpathmoveto{\northeast}` moves the current position to the `\northeast`-anchor. This is done directly before the for loop. Inside the loop, the current position is moved to the left by `\pgfutil@tempdima` each iteration. This moves the current position to the left incrementeally. (No problem, have a nice day/evening)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the loop to become a bit more explicit, which seems to work. You are right about `\pgfpathmoveto{\northeast}`. I also gave the shape and node styles different names. (Let me also mention that you could also work with `pic`s and `local bounding box`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{fblock}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is a rectanble
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]

  \foregroundpath{
    \setlength{\pgf@ya}{\pgfshapeminheight}
    \setlength{\pgf@xa}{\pgfshapeminwidth}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgf@xa / 10}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
    {  
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-\i*\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-\i*\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2\pgf@ya}}}
    }
  }
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, minimum width = 4cm, minimum height = 0.4cm,
shape=fblock}}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[every block/.style={draw}]
\node[block] (p1) at (0,0)  {};
\node[above] at (p1.north) {Plaintext 1};
\node[block, left=1.5cm] (iv) at (p1.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew that one could do calculations inside `\pgfpoint`. That  makes everything a lot simpler! I also found out in the meantime that `\pgfpointadd` internally uses `\pgf@xa` which might explain the problem.